# python module compiled by SWIG returns wrong result

Tags: python, module, swig, double-precision

I'm just playing around SWIG to make python' module for specific C library. I got the trouble with double and float variables. Here an example:

```
/***** simple.c *****/
#include <stdio.h>
double doublefun(double b){
        printf("c(%g)",b);
        return b+12.5;
}

float floatfun(float b){
        printf("c(%f)",b);
        return b+12.5;
}

int intfun(int b){
        printf("c(%d)",b);
        return b+12;
}

/***** simple.i *****/
%module simple
%{
%}

extern double doublefun(double);
extern float floatfun(float);
extern int intfun(int);
```

AND

```
#***** simpletest.py *****#
import simple

print "i:",simple.intfun(2)
print "f:",simple.floatfun(2.3)
print "d:",simple.doublefun(2.3)
```

The result is:

```
i:c(2) 14
f:c(36893488147419103232.000000) 30.0
d:c(2.3) 6.0
```

Any ideas why it happens?

**P.S.** If I call functions from C code ....

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
        printf("i::%d\n",intfun(2));
        printf("f::%f\n",floatfun(2.3));
        printf("d::%g\n",doublefun(2.3));
        return 0;
}
```

Everything is fine:

```
c(2)i::14
c(2.300000)f::14.800000
c(2.3)d::14.8
```

Comment: add what happens with `floatfun` when you launch the C code alone ? not launched by python, calling it from a simple c main function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the header as shown in [the first example in the docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Python.html#Python_nn2):

```
%{
#include "simple.h"
%}
```

then you should get:

```
i:c(2) 14
f:c(2.300000) 14.8000001907
d:c(2.3) 14.8
```

See [full example](https://gist.github.com/zed/5330891).

Comment: thank you. It works. Why there is nothing about this in SWIG documentation? Why it happens?